# how to overlay boxplot across a scatterplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot, boxplot

fake data

```
set.seed( 123)
x<-rnorm(1000, mean=60,sd=20)
y <-  exp(-10 +  .95*log(x^3)) + rnorm(1000,mean=1,sd=1)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
cls.x <- quantile(df$x, seq(.1, .9, by=.1))
df$x.class <- findInterval(df$x, cls.x)
df$x.class <- as.factor(df$x.class)
head(df)
```

Neither the following work

```
plot(df$x,df$y,col=3)
par(new=T)
boxplot(y~x.class, data=df,xlab="",ylab="",xaxt="n")
```

nor this

```
boxplot(y~x.class, data=df,xlab="",ylab="",xaxt="n")
points(df$x,df$y,col=3)
```

Using ggplot, the closest I get is using something like

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x.class,y))+geom_boxplot() + geom_point()
```

Unfortunately, It does not show the real variability in the-axis.
I tried with the jitter option, but I was not able to force the plot to use the real variability of the X-variable

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Ps: I am aware of the bplot.xy() function in Rlab, however, that function does not allow me to change colours of the boxplot, or plot the dots first.

```
library(Rlab)
bplot.xy( x,y,  N=10)
points( x,y, pch=".", col=3, cex=3)
```

Comment: Did you mean instead `points(df$x.class, df$y)`? Your x-axis includes 1 through 10 (for your 0-9 factors in `x.class`), but your `x` ranges from 3.8  to 124.8 ... well off screen.

Answer (score 2):

Is the following what you want?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = x.class)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.10) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.50)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @RuiBarradas, that is exactly what I wanted to achieve     
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group=x.class)) + 
      geom_point(alpha = 0.10,col="black")+ geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.50) 
    p + theme(legend.position = "none")

Comment: @ChristianSalas-Eljatib Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `df$x` varies from 3 to 124, whereas your x-axis is from 1 to 10. In base graphics, you can do this:

```r
plot(jitter(as.integer(df$x.class)), df$y, col=3, type="p", xlab = "", ylab = "", xaxt = "n")
boxplot(y~x.class, data=df,xlab="",ylab="",xaxt="n", add = TRUE)
```

I added `jitter` to help break out the distribution. You might also try `pch=16` to make the dots solid, and perhaps use transparency (e.g., `col="#aaffaa22"` for the dots).

[image: base boxplot-over-scatter]

Comment: thanks, @r2evans. I want to avoid jittering. I just compute the x.class for drawing the boxplot, I know they are on different scales.